# In France, do I have to pay rent even though the landlord re-let the apartment before the end of the contract?

Tags: france, rental

My contract was supposed to end in June, but I told my landlord in February that I will be moving on in end of May. As my lease requires a 1 month notice only to terminate the contract, I sent a letter to my landlord on 28th April to terminate the contract. He replied that he received the request on 1st May. So I paid him the rent for the last month and he sent me back a rental receipt for 1st May-31st May.

He then has found a new tenant and is letting out on 20th May. He then requests me to vacate the house and handover the keys on 17th, but he is not paying me back the rent for the rest of the month. He threatens me that he could have actually charged me for the rent in June as well as the contract is supposed to end in June.

Am I liable to pay for the rent until 30th May even though he is re-letting the apartment on 20th?

Comment: You will have to look at your contract to be certain, but most rental are as you assume, i.e. that you are paying ahead a month. If he gets to pushy, have lawyer send him a nice letter about France tenancy law.

Comment: Thanks a lot ouflak! The contract did not specify anything except that I have to give a 1month notice for terminating the contract...He even threatens me that he is going to take a large part of the deposit if I am not coordinating, even though we haven't done the check out!

Comment: It seems like a dirty trick, because 1 month notice for May would mean, you need to give the letter until 1 May, which mean you'd be liable to pay rent until the end of June, but also, you can stay there until the end of June and no day shorter.

Comment: @RLH: do you mind giving us an update of your situation, and maybe answering your own question? That could help other people